# Accessing services from OSGi fragment bundles

Tags: osgi, embedded-jetty, osgi-bundle, osgi-fragment

In my project, there is an OSGi bundle which exposes an interface `com.xyx.EventProvider` as a declerative service.

There is another 3rd party bundle `org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty`, to which I have attached a fragment bundle `com.xyz.jetty.customizer`.

This fragment bundle needs to access the service exposed via the interface `com.xyx.EventProvider`.

The problem is that fragment bundles don't have Activators, so it does not have reference to the BundleContext and therefore it cannot access any service.

Is there a way in OSGi to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried FrameworkUtil.getBundle()? Never used it myself, but it seems the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always hate to suggest using `FrameworkUtil.getBundle().getBundleContext()` because it's such a hack, but in this case it seems to be the only solution.

You will need to pass in a class that is defined by the host bundle, because fragments cannot have a BundleContext (i.e. the `getBundleContext` call would return null).

Comment: Having BundleContext is one way to get reference to the service that I could think of. Is there any other way to get service reference in a fragment bundle (in declerative way or programatically)?

Comment: If there was another way then I wouldn't have suggested the above solution, because it's really a hack. At least, I can't think of one. For example you can't use DS because the Service-Component header is ignored in fragment.